# Как заменить значения в одной таблице значениями из другой таблицы, либо из словаря в pandas

Tags: python, pandas

[image: Таблицы.]

Необходимо заменить значения в колонке from Талицы 1 на значения from Таблицы 2 по ключу from_id, причем заменить только значения в колонке from, не меняя и не удаляя значения в остальных столбцах.

Также сделал словарь значений из таблицы 2:

```
dict = {user02: Петя (1), user06: Женя (1), user07: Женя (2), user10: Маша (1)}
```

Т.е. без разницы, что использовать Таблицу 2 или словарь.
Во всем интернете не нашел рабочего ответа на свой вопрос. Перепробовал кучу способов, и все не то. Просьба помочь рабочим решением.

Answer (score 1):

Можно применить метод `merge()`, сопоставив нужные значения из двух фреймов. Потом соответствующие значения (которые не NaN) просто присвоить исходному столбцу в нужные позиции с помощью `loc` и булева массива.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'fromid': ['user01', 'user02', 'user03', 'user04', 'user05', 'user06', 'user07', 'user08', 'user09', 'user10'],
     'from': ['Петя', 'Петя', 'Ваня', 'Саша', 'Женя', 'Женя', 'Женя', 'Даша', 'Маша', 'Маша'],
     'text': ['Запись 1', 'Запись 2', 'Запись 3', 'Запись 4', 'Запись 5', 'Запись 6', 'Запись 7', 'Запись 8',
              'Запись 9', 'Запись 10']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame(
    {'fromid': ['user02', 'user06', 'user07', 'user10'], 'from': ['Петя (1)', 'Женя (1)', 'Женя (2)', 'Маша (1)']})

df3 = df1.merge(df2, how='left', on='fromid', suffixes=('', '1'))
df1.loc[idx, 'from'] = df3.loc[(idx := ~df3['from1'].isna()), 'from1']
print(df1)
```

```
   fromid      from       text
0  user01      Петя   Запись 1
1  user02  Петя (1)   Запись 2
2  user03      Ваня   Запись 3
3  user04      Саша   Запись 4
4  user05      Женя   Запись 5
5  user06  Женя (1)   Запись 6
6  user07  Женя (2)   Запись 7
7  user08      Даша   Запись 8
8  user09      Маша   Запись 9
9  user10  Маша (1)  Запись 10
```

Comment: Сам по себе ваш код рабочий. Но когда прилаживаю его к своим данным (которых намного больше, чем в примере) , то вылетают ошибки. Воспользуюсь способом со словарем, который работает. Предупреждение : Creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences (which is a list-or-tuple of lists-or-tuples-or ndarrays with different lengths or shapes) is deprecated. If you meant to do this, you must specify 'dtype=object' when creating the ndarray.. Ошибка: TypeError: unhashable type: 'Series' . К тому же код слишком громоздок и излишне загружает ПК.

Answer (score 0):

Что-то типа такого:

```py
dict_ = {'user02': 'Петя (1)',
         'user06': 'Женя (1)',
         'user07': 'Женя (2)',
         'user10': 'Маша (1)'} 

df['from'] = df.apply(lambda x: dict_.get(x['from_id'], x['from']), axis=1)
```

А для первого варианта (без словаря) - приведите сначала данные в воспроизводимом виде.

Comment: Предложенный вариант замены значений по ключу из словаря не работает. Вылетает ошибка: KeyError: 'from_id'

Comment: @Vitalik Ось нужно указать ещё, добавил

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь заработало с помощью словаря, задача решена!